# Cannot read a property in React-0.13.3 CJSX code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, cjsx

I'm working on a react.js app which will be displaying tweets. unfortunately there's an error that says, "Cannot read property 'profileImageUrl' of Undefined." which is this line:

```
<img src={@props.details.tweet.user.profileImageUrl} />
```

I'm using React 0.13.3 to do this. Here's a piece of my Coffeescript CJSX code that includes the property in question

```
Tweet = React.createClass
  propTypes:
    details: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired

  render: ->
    <article className="tweet-container">
        <div className="tweet-profile-picture">
            <img src={@props.details.tweet.user.profileImageUrl} />
        </div>
        <div className="tweet-body">
            <header className="tweet-header">
                <div className="tweet-metadata">
                    <a href="//twitter.com/#  {@props.details.tweet.user.screenName}">
                    <span className="name">{@props.details.tweet.user.name}</span>
                    <span className="screenName">{@props.details.tweet.user.screenName}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <p>{@props.details.tweet.text}</p>
    </div>
    <div className="timestamp">
        <a href="//twitter.com/#{@props.details.tweet.user.screenName}/status/#{@props.details.tweet.idStr}">
            <time datetime={@props.details.tweet.createdAt}><moment(@props.details.createdAtTimestamp).fromNow()}</time>
        </a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Why is it saying that the profile image url is undefined? Where would be the best place to start to fix this? Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the service. It turns out `@props.details.tweet.user` was null in the api. The code is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent Component of Tweet which is wrapping this component

In your parentComponent there would `<Tweet details={details}/>`

Comment: I do have that line in another file `render: ->
   details =
   <div className="full-row #{@props.line} contents" key={@props.line}>
     {_.map @props.data, (details) ->
      <Tweet key={details.tweet.idStr} details={details} />
     }
   </div>` I tried changing that line but that didn't work unfortunately.